# Decrypt an encrypted string using SFDC certificate

Tags: decrypt

I have SFDC certificate installed in my sandbox. let's say it "ABCD.cert"

Now a external system sends a string value which is encrypted via same SFDC certificate ie; "ABCD.cert". Now I have to decrypt that data in APEX. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with keys managed via Certificates and Key Management.

[Crypto.decrypt(...)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) supports several symmetric-key AES algorithms. When you encrypt plaintext off SF platform with a key, the same key has to be available in SF to decrypt your ciphertext. This is symmetric encryption/decryption. Certificates and Key Management is primarily designed to support asymmetric algorithms where you have a public key (contained within a X.509 certificate) and a corresponding private key. Certificates and Key Management also supports symmetric keys for use with Classic encryption but these keys are not available via Apex.

Recommended workaround: generate your own symmetric key off the platform and store it in a protected [custom setting or custom metadata](http://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets).  See this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256608/classic-master-encryption-keys-in-apex/256619) for more details.

Comment: So that means that I have to generate a key using the Cryto Class and send it external system's admin and they will use the same key to encrypt and send the string to me.

Comment: @Swagata Yes, that will work.

Comment: Blob key1 = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
System.debug(' KEY '+String.valueOf(key1));                                                               Unfortunately it is not showing key value . Do you know how to generate the key and put it in string format so that I can share?

Comment: Convert it to base64 or hex via [EncodingUtil](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)